# Adding Event Handler for Dynamically Created to window Form

Tags: c#, asp.net, window

I have a window form where I am creating a list of Checkboxes. The number of checkboxes created are based upon how many items are returned from the database. I've been able to create the checkboxes; however, I am not sure how to add event handlers for these checkboxes. For example, I'd like to add an OnCheckedChanged or CheckStateChanged event. How can I add these events? Also, I would appreciate any other suggestion. I am a total newbie to programming.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBoxes = new CheckBox[listGroup.Count()];
            for (int i = 0; i < listGroup.Count(); i++)
            {
                CheckBoxes[i] = new CheckBox();
                CheckBoxes[i].Text = listGroup.ElementAt(i).GroupName;
                CheckBoxes[i].Name = "txt" + listGroup.ElementAt(i).GroupName.Replace(' ', '_');
                CheckBoxes[i].CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(CheckBoxes[i]+"_CheckedChanged");
                CheckBoxes[i].Width = 200;
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    CheckBoxes[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(5, 10);
                }
                else if (i == 1)
                {
                    CheckBoxes[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(5, 40);
                }
                else if (i == 2)
                {
                    CheckBoxes[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(5, 80);
                }
                this.Controls.Add(CheckBoxes[i]);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //...
    CheckBoxes[i].CheckedChanged += checkBoxes_CheckedChanged;
    CheckBoxes[i].CheckStateChanged += checkBoxes_CheckStateChanged;
}

void checkBoxes_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ //do stuff when checked changed }

void checkBoxes_CheckStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ //do stuff when check state changed }
```

Note: this will give identical event handling for all of your checkboxes.
If you want to do different things for different textboxes, you have to name the eventhandler differently and define that eventhandler.

A more efficient way to set the location of your checkboxes

```
    for (int i = 0; i < listGroup.Count(); i++)
    {
        CheckBoxes[i] = new CheckBox();
        CheckBoxes[i].Text = listGroup.ElementAt(i).GroupName;
        CheckBoxes[i].Name = "txt" + listGroup.ElementAt(i).GroupName.Replace(' ', '_');
        CheckBoxes[i].CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(CheckBoxes[i] + "_CheckedChanged");
        CheckBoxes[i].Width = 200;
        //set location based on index of i
        CheckBoxes[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(5, 10 + (i * 30));
        this.Controls.Add(CheckBoxes[i]);
    }
```

Comment: @Chris....Thank you. As far as the way that I am setting the location of the checkboxes, is there a better or more efficient way of doing it.

Comment: I was not sure where to ask this questions, so I am going to ask it here as a comment. When Ia m not sure how to use a control, what is the best way to learn how to use it? For example, I read some of the documentation that Microsoft Posted on system.windows.forms.checkbox, and I did not fully understand what I was reading.

Comment: For dynamically created objects, you have to set the location manually, so your code looks fine.
Microsoft documentations usually have examples at the end, try to work  off of those to learn the different attributes for different controls.

Answer (score 1):

```
        private void LoadNewCheckboxes()
    {
        dynamic listGroupCount = 10;

        List<System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox> CheckBoxes = new List<System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= listGroupCount - 1; i++)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox chkbox = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox();

            chkbox.Text = i.ToString();
            //listGroup.ElementAt(i).GroupName
            chkbox.Name = "txt" + i.ToString();
            //listGroup.ElementAt(i).GroupName.Replace(" "c, "_"c)
            chkbox.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(chkbox_CheckedChanged);
            chkbox.CheckStateChanged += new EventHandler(chkbox_CheckStateChanged);
            chkbox.Width = 200;
            chkbox.AutoSize = true;

            this.Controls.Add(chkbox);
            CheckBoxes.Add(chkbox);

            if (i == 0)
            {
                chkbox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(5, 10);
            }
            else
            {
                chkbox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(5, (CheckBoxes[i - 1].Top + CheckBoxes[i - 1].Height + 10));
            }

        }
    }

    private void chkbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox chkbox = (System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox)sender;
        if (chkbox != null)
        {
            //do somthing
            Debug.WriteLine("chkbox_CheckedChanged");
            Debug.WriteLine(chkbox.Text);
            Debug.WriteLine(chkbox.Checked.ToString());
            Debug.WriteLine(chkbox.Name.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void chkbox_CheckStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox chkbox = (System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox)sender;
        if (chkbox != null)
        {
            //do somthing
            Debug.WriteLine("chkbox_CheckStateChanged");
            Debug.WriteLine(chkbox.Text);
            Debug.WriteLine(chkbox.Checked.ToString());
            Debug.WriteLine(chkbox.Name.ToString());
        }
    }
```